# Observe Javascript object that is external to polymer Web component

Tags: polymer-1.0

is it possible to observe an external Javascript object or module and have it bound to a Web components property. If the external Javascript object changes my Web component property should change.

I'll try get a code example up of my problem.

Comment: app.js has "app.var" which is passed to element in template via attr "my-var"={{var}} "  where std property listens :       properties: {
        myVar: {
          type: Object,
          notify: true,
          observer: '_myvarChanged'

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try and let you know :)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work myVar is undefined inside the component.

Comment: If var is defined, the template , as attr val receives as "my-var " , which polymer 1 binds to property "myVar"

Comment: pass in value 1, then when u get "onReady" from the component, use a function up in app.js to change valueOf app.js.var  . this will fire the notifier in the component that is listener( comp.myVar )

Comment: I am struggling with same issue. Can you post a working code?